# Problems when installing segway-rmp package

Tags: ros, python, roscd, packages, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. I downloaded the `segway-rmp-ros-pkg` from here:

http://wiki.ros.org/segway_rmp

I followed all the steps up until doing the `rosinstall`. I put in the wrong path to the `ros` directory and got the according error message, until I realized that it was in `/opt/ros/hydro`. After running that command succesfuly, I was prompted to run a "source" command by `rosinstall`. After doing so, I was not able to proceed to the next step, which is running `roscd segway_rmp`. This is, however, not the main issue. I closed the terminal and tried opening a new one, but whenever I now open a Terminal, I don't get the $ sign with username, but the terminal is completely empty. Only when I hit `ctrl-c` do I get the command line back. Sometimes, when I hit `ctrl-c`, I get a message telling me about latest tracebacks, all going to python files. I am unsure what went wrong here, maybe someone can help me!

I already restarted the computer, but I keep getting the same issue with every new terminal I open.

Thanks,
Marc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174879/problems-when-installing-segway-rmp-package/) by [Marc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18988/marc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2014-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That suggests that you have something inside your .bashrc which is hanging. The tracebacks may help you with finding what your ctrl-c is interrupting.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18988/marc/) on 2014-06-25**:
I got onto that route after searching... I reset my .bashrc file by copying an original from etc/skel. With that setup, I am able to start a new terminal, but obviously I lost all my ROS stuff since the environmental vars are not there anymore. I try to re-add ROS source, but the terminal hangs.

**Comment by [Marc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18988/marc/) on 2014-06-25**:
Is it possible the setup.bash is corrupted? Is there a way to reset it together with the other files in /opt/ros/hydro? Thanks a lot!